# Flurry Analytics for Android: Data not being sent to Flurry dashboard?

Tags: android, http, flurry

I am attempting to integrate `Flurry Analytics` into a simple app I created. I have correctly downloaded and added the `SDK` to my application. However when I run the app there is no data being sent to the `Flurry dashboard` despite logcat messages confirming it was, such as:

```
10-20 06:56:51.756: W/FlurryAgent(1355): FlurryDataSender: report 7ab955c2-f035-4c54-b606-a68a8edb76c6 sent. HTTP response: 200
10-20 06:57:08.356: W/FlurryAgent(1355): End session with context: com.example.testflurry.MainActivity@b3d14db8 count:0
10-20 06:57:18.726: W/FlurryAgent(1355): Finalize session
10-20 06:57:21.076: W/FlurryAgent(1355): FlurryDataSender: report dbf1e31f-f136-4c10-ba97-dc5760dfbbd8 sent. HTTP response: 200
```

**Android Activity Code:**

```
package com.example.testflurry;

import com.flurry.android.FlurryAgent;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();
        FlurryAgent.onStartSession(this, "xxxx");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop()
    {
        super.onStop();     
        FlurryAgent.onEndSession(this);
    }

}
```

**Full Logcat Output:**

```
10-20 06:56:48.746: I/dalvikvm(1355): Could not find method com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient$Info.getId, referenced from method com.flurry.sdk.dj.v
10-20 06:56:48.746: W/dalvikvm(1355): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 10064: Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/identifier/AdvertisingIdClient$Info;.getId ()Ljava/lang/String;
10-20 06:56:48.896: D/dalvikvm(1355): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0042
10-20 06:56:48.946: I/dalvikvm(1355): Could not find method com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient$Info.isLimitAdTrackingEnabled, referenced from method com.flurry.sdk.dj.o
10-20 06:56:48.946: W/dalvikvm(1355): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 10065: Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/identifier/AdvertisingIdClient$Info;.isLimitAdTrackingEnabled ()Z
10-20 06:56:48.946: D/dalvikvm(1355): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
10-20 06:56:48.966: I/dalvikvm(1355): Could not find method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable, referenced from method com.flurry.sdk.dw.b
10-20 06:56:48.986: W/FlurryAgent(1355): Start session with context: com.example.testflurry.MainActivity@b3d14db8 count:0
10-20 06:56:48.996: W/dalvikvm(1355): VFY: unable to resolve static method 10067: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil;.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable (Landroid/content/Context;)I
10-20 06:56:48.996: D/dalvikvm(1355): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0009
10-20 06:56:49.006: I/dalvikvm(1355): Could not find method com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo, referenced from method com.flurry.sdk.dw.c
10-20 06:56:49.006: W/dalvikvm(1355): VFY: unable to resolve static method 10066: Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/identifier/AdvertisingIdClient;.getAdvertisingIdInfo (Landroid/content/Context;)Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/identifier/AdvertisingIdClient$Info;
10-20 06:56:49.006: D/dalvikvm(1355): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x000a
10-20 06:56:49.026: W/dalvikvm(1355): VFY: unable to resolve exception class 1277 (Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException;)
10-20 06:56:49.026: W/dalvikvm(1355): VFY: unable to find exception handler at addr 0x29
10-20 06:56:49.026: W/dalvikvm(1355): VFY:  rejected Lcom/flurry/sdk/dw;.c ()Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/identifier/AdvertisingIdClient$Info;
10-20 06:56:49.026: W/dalvikvm(1355): VFY:  rejecting opcode 0x0d at 0x0029
10-20 06:56:49.026: W/dalvikvm(1355): VFY:  rejected Lcom/flurry/sdk/dw;.c ()Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/identifier/AdvertisingIdClient$Info;
10-20 06:56:49.026: W/dalvikvm(1355): Verifier rejected class Lcom/flurry/sdk/dw;
10-20 06:56:49.026: W/System.err(1355): java.lang.VerifyError: com/flurry/sdk/dw
10-20 06:56:49.036: W/System.err(1355):     at com.flurry.sdk.dj$1.a(SourceFile:247)
10-20 06:56:49.036: W/System.err(1355):     at com.flurry.sdk.fc.run(SourceFile:49)
10-20 06:56:49.036: W/System.err(1355):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
10-20 06:56:49.036: W/System.err(1355):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
10-20 06:56:49.036: W/System.err(1355):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
10-20 06:56:49.046: W/System.err(1355):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
10-20 06:56:49.436: D/dalvikvm(1355): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 299K, 11% free 2957K/3312K, paused 30ms, total 32ms
10-20 06:56:49.486: D/gralloc_goldfish(1355): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
10-20 06:56:51.386: D/dalvikvm(1355): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 410K, 14% free 3051K/3520K, paused 31ms, total 31ms
10-20 06:56:51.756: W/FlurryAgent(1355): FlurryDataSender: report 7ab955c2-f035-4c54-b606-a68a8edb76c6 sent. HTTP response: 200
10-20 06:57:08.356: W/FlurryAgent(1355): End session with context: com.example.testflurry.MainActivity@b3d14db8 count:0
10-20 06:57:18.726: W/FlurryAgent(1355): Finalize session
10-20 06:57:21.076: W/FlurryAgent(1355): FlurryDataSender: report dbf1e31f-f136-4c10-ba97-dc5760dfbbd8 sent. HTTP response: 200
```

Is the information sending successfully from the app to Flurry?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add [Google Play Services](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html) to your project. You will also need to add this to your app's manifest, inside the *application* tag:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Comment: Including full Google Play Services is a waste of precious 64K methods, so I repacked jar excluding map, ads, and other useless for me sdks. What does flurry actually use? It looks like as soon I repacked GP jar Flurry stopped working.

Comment: @Tertium Have you managed to fix this issue, I excluded some of the items as well from the full package? What does Flurry actually use?

Comment: They respond they actually use nothing if you don't use their ads. But it looks like flurry works only in release binaries, not from eclipse, and it send data from session only when the next session starts